# Convert dictionary with list into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, flatten

I have a Python dictionary

```
result_dict = { 'kontonummer': None,
                'industryPredictions': {'Supermarket': 0.006795256825841207,
                                        'Cars': 0.01113155396585519},
                'paymentmethods': ['Klarna SofortUeberweisung',
                                   'Klarna Ratenkauf.',
                                   'Ueberweisung'],
                'pricesAmount': 2721,
                'pricesMean': 30.796045571481077,
                'pricesQ25': 12.99}
```

I want to flatten the dictionary in order to convert it to a **pandas** *dataframe* similar to this:

```
  kontonummer   industryPredictions.Supermarket industryPredictions.Cars    paymentmethods  pricesAmount    pricesMean  pricesQ25
0    None                 0.006795                        0.011132      ['Klarna Sofort...]    2721               30.79    12.99
```

I know how to convert a *dict* into a *dataframe*. My problem is to convert the dictionary into the desired structure.

As you can see, there are 2 challenges:

1. `industryPredictions`
2. The list given in `paymentmethods`

Comment: `pd.json_normalize(result_dict)` ??

Comment: *My problem is to convert the dictionary into the desired structure.* Do you want the dataframe or you want the dictionary?

Comment: Well, I am very suprised that the simple code snipped from @Nk03 solves my problem. I did't know this. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), and pass the dictionary you have

```py
>>> pd.json_normalize(result_dict)

  kontonummer                                                paymentmethods  pricesAmount  pricesMean  pricesQ25  industryPredictions.Supermarket  industryPredictions.Cars
0        None  [Klarna SofortUeberweisung, Klarna Ratenkauf., Ueberweisung]          2721   30.796046      12.99                         0.006795                  0.011132
```

It will work even if you have multiple such dictionaries in a list like : `pd.json_normalize([result_dict, result_dict])`